# OpenVZ container runs with only 3 processes

Tags: linux, process, openvz

I upgraded a Debian 6 OpenVZ container that contains a web application to Debian 8. Everything worked great.

Today I rebooted the container and it only starts with 3 NPROCs:

[image: Screenshot]

I can access the container but no services are running, and when I try to run a service I get the error:

`Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused`

What can I do to force the process to start?

Comment: What host kernel version are you running? Are any of your "working" containers Debian 8?

Comment: pve-manager/3.1-24/060bd5a6 (running kernel: 2.6.32-26-pve). after upgrade the container and the web application run very well but after reboot i get the problem above